# How to pass data from ViewController to embed View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have a View Controller, where user taps button and moves to Second view, and I want to pass some data to it, but Second view has a Navigation View Controller, so prepareForSegue() doesn't work here. Shall I pass data to Navigation View and then to Second View or do something else?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers  it can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController
, the following solution is more correct: use "topViewController" of the UINavitaionController.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    let segueID = segue.identifier ?? ""

    switch segueID
    {
        case "toMyNextVC":
            let nc = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
            let destinationVC = nc.topViewController as! MyNextViewController
            destinationVC.varToPass = myVarToPass

        default:
            break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)moveToSecondViewButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondViewController.data = data;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data size is moderate, you can use `NSNotificationCenter` for passing the data.

**Sender Class**

```
- (void)sendNotification {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:YOUR_DATA];
}
```

**Receiver class**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) 
        name:@"myNotification"
        object:nil];
}

- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"myNotification"]) {

        //doSomething here.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Dont segue from your viewcontroller to UIViewController. you must segue viewcontroller to UINavigationController of new UIViewController. You can pass data in prepareForSegue method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
// Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "showNavigationController"{
        let navController : UINavigationController  = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
        let viewController : UIViewController = navController.viewControllers[0] as! UIViewController
        viewController.data = yourData
    }
}
```